# Equivalence relation on real projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I have to give an equivalence relation on real projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that $\mathbb{P}^2/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$, the two-dimensional sphere.

Once I have the equivalence relation I know how to prove that it is indeed homeomorphic. However I don't know how to find such an equivalence relation. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Is it complex projective space?

Comment: It is real projective plane, I've changed the question.

Comment: $\Bbb{P}^2$ is obtained from $(D^2,S^1)$ by identifying antipodal points in the subspace $S^1$ and then we obtain the pair $(\Bbb{P}^2,A)$. Collapse now $A\simeq S^1$ in $\Bbb{P}^2$ to a point. Then we obtain $(S^2,pt.)$

Comment: Do I understand it right that we need to collapse $S^1$ to a point? Could you help me with the proof that it is homeomorphic to $S^2$? I want to do it by using the universal property, but then I need a continuous function from $\mathbb{P}^2\to S^2$, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Desperado's answer may be more helpfull. @csmath

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it works, but you may consider the following equivalence relation. Let $u_1:=(x_1:y_1:z_1), \ u_2:=(x_2:y_2:z_2)\in \mathbb P^2$, and define $u_1 \sim u_2$ if and only if $u_1=u_2$ or $z_1=z_2=0$.
Geometrically you are  identifying all the directions contained in the $xy$-plane, which should represent the "south pole"; the other points are not identified and represents the other points of the sphere, e.g. $(0:0:1)$ will be the "north pole".